# How to generate all pxq matrices with n values "1" with no columns or lines having two "1" (chess n-towers problem)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to generate all matrices (p,q) having exactly n "1" value with no column or line having more than one "1" value (a kind of chess n towers problem).

Here is a simple example in python for p=4, q=4 and n=2:

```
for i1 in range(4*4):
    x1, y1 = i1//4, i1%4
    for i2 in range(i+1,4*4):
        x2, y2 = i2//4, i2%4
        if x1 != x2 and y1 != y2:
           print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

It is not really efficient and it would be cumbersome to write if for n=9 (for example). Is there a vectorized way of doing it?

Also, what would be the formula to count them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, product
from math import comb, factorial
import numpy as np
```

This function returns a generator of all possible matrices:

```
def boards(p, q, n):
    comb = combinations(range(p), n)
    perm = permutations(range(q), n)
    coords = product(comb, perm)

    def make_board(c):
        arr = np.zeros((p, q), dtype=int)
        arr[c[0], c[1]] = 1
        return arr

    return map(make_board, coords)
```

This function returns the number of all possible matrices without generating them:

```
def num_boards(p, q, n):
    return comb(p, n) * comb(q, n) * factorial(n)
```

For example:

```
num_boards(4, 4, 2)
```

gives:

```
72
```

Printing the matrices:

```
for m in boards(4, 4, 2):
    print(m, "\n")
```

It gives:

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]] 

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]] 

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]] 
....
```

Comment: Testing your implementation, the 4/4/3 seems off:

`print(num_boards(4,4,2))` gives 72

`print(num_boards(4,4,3))` gives 96

`print(num_boards(4,4,4))` gives 24

Comment: @NicolasRougier This looks correct, why does it seem off?

Comment: Just surprised that by the progression 72, 96, 24. I was expecting a decreasing number of board when n increases. Very elegant code by the way.